# How to add parameters in a function on a AddEventListener

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, dom-events

I'm trying to create a Web mapping application with some layers, the idea it's that I have some checkboxes and when I click them the layer is added or removed (I have already done that) but there are a lot of layers and of course a lot of code, I realize that with a function I can do the work, but after hours and hours of work it still doesn't work and I'm ready to give up:

```
function turnon(idlayer, layer) {
  var local = document.getElementById(layer);//verify whick checkbox is the one for the layer
  if (local.checked == true) {
    map.addOverlay(layer);//an OpenLayers method to add the layer to the map
  } else {
    map.removeOverlay(layer);
  }
}
var wmsSector=document.getElementById('sector')//This is the checkbox
wmsSector.addEventListener("click", turnon);
```

The thing its that I don't know how to add the parameter on the `addEventListener` Handler I have tried this:

```
wmsSector.addEventListener("click",turnon('wmsSector',sector))
```

I appreciate any help you can give me, because right now the application works but I believe it can be more elegant.

Comment: Bind the arguments with `.bind` or pass a function expression that wraps around the function and calls it with arguments

Answer (score 0):

I would be more generic in attaching the listeners so that the checkbox provides the id or name of the overlay to attach, e.g.

```js
// For testing
var map = {
  addOverlay: function(layer) {
    console.log(layer + ' added');
  },
  removeOverlay: function(layer) {
    console.log(layer + ' removed');
  }
};

// Toggle layer on or off
function toggleLayer(evt) {
  this.checked? map.addOverlay(this.value) : map.removeOverlay(this.value);
}

// Add listener to each layer checkbox
window.onload = function() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.layerToggle'),  function(node) {
    node.addEventListener('click', toggleLayer, false);
  });
}
```

```html
<label for="wmsSector"><input type="checkbox" id="wmsSector" value="wmsSector" class="layerToggle">&nbsp;WMS Sector</label><br>
<label for="vegetation"><input type="checkbox" id="vegetation" value="vegetation" class="layerToggle">&nbsp;Vegetation</label><br>
<label for="adminBoundaries"><input type="checkbox" id="adminBoundaries" value="adminBoundaries" class="layerToggle">&nbsp;Admin Boundaries</label>
```

I've used the *value* attribute, but you could also use a *data-
** attribute, say `data-mapLayer="wmsSector"` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use an anonymous function,

```
wmsSector.addEventListener("click",function(){
    turnon('wmsSector',sector);
})
```